# Android; getting an "the application has stopped unexpectedly" during runtime

Tags: java, android, android-intent, layout

OK, I have the simplest android studio application.. and it's killing me! I'm not an experience Android or Java developer.

I've searched online and I get older posts about declaring the activity in the manifest, I did that!

I have 3 activities;

1. Splashscreen, runs great.
2. WEMProject, runs great.
3. NoNetworkConnections, "the application has stopped unexpectedly"
   during runtime.

In my WEMProject I just want to load a Webview if I have a network connection, if not, show a nice "No network present" screen.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wemproject);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://my.wem.io");
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WEMProject.this, NoNetworkConnection.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This works great, the network check works fine, but if there is no network the:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoNetworkConnection.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

part causes the error.. WHY?

The activity is:

```
public class NoNetworkConnection extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_network_connection);
} }
```

I've declared the activity in my AndroidManifest.XML

```
    <activity
        android:name=".NoNetworkConnection"
        android:parentActivityName=".WEMProject"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_no_network_connection"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
    </activity>
```

The debug part of the android log:

```
04-06 14:12:39.668 15630-15630/io.wem.my.mywem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: io.wem.my.mywem, PID: 15630
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.wem.my.mywem/io.wem.my.mywem.WEMProject}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.NetworkInfo.getTypeName()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.NetworkInfo.getTypeName()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at io.wem.my.mywem.WEMProject.haveNetworkConnection(WEMProject.java:33)
                                                                 at io.wem.my.mywem.WEMProject.onCreate(WEMProject.java:61)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

As requested the haveNetworkConnection() method:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (netInfo.isConnected())
            haveConnectedWifi = true;
    if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        if (netInfo.isConnected())
            haveConnectedMobile = true;

    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you show the logs?

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ [The error message from logcat.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this#23353174)

Comment: added to the original post. Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: Like the error log says, in `WEMProject.java` line 33 you are calling `getTypeName()` on a `NetworkInfo` object that has not been initialized. You could add the `haveNetworkConnection()` method to your question, so that somebody can have a look at it and write a proper answer.

Comment: Can you post the code for the haveNetworkConnection() method

Comment: Added the haveNetworkConnection() method. Learned something allready from this thread, didn't know about the log with the debug info ;-) could have found that error myself if I knew where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Android's [ConnectivityManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()) on `getActiveNetworkInfo()`:

> Returns | a NetworkInfo object for the current default network or null
>   if no default network is currently active

So, it may well return `null` and your code should handle this case.

For example:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (netInfo != null) {
    if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (netInfo.isConnected())
            haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (netInfo.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense as I was testing with the phone in airplane mode, this solved the issue.